# Please review my code.Need Input

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im using the following code for records inserting into database field.I want to correct the following  if and else condition because when records are inserting in database it should echo 0 but it is giving 1.Im unable to figure out the problem.Please  i need correction in my code.

```
<?php    /****************dbfile.php****/
$data = $_REQUEST['columns_one'];
$store_data = explode(",",$data);
//print_r($store_data);
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("formbuilder",$con);

$query = "INSERT INTO record(form_id,form_structure) VALUES('1','value')";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    echo 0;
}
else
{
    echo 1;

}

?>

<script>   <!--- ajax call----->
$.post("dbfile.php", {columns_one:columns_one },  
            function(result){  
                //if the result is 1  
                if(result == 1){
                alert('success');  

                    return true;
                }else{ 
                alert('fail'); 

                    return false;

                }  
</script>
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You are using [an obsolete database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: @YamMarcovic — This is a (very poorly expressed) debugging question, not a request for a code review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong function. `mysql_num_rows` will not return the rows affected by INSERT statements, see here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Use `mysql_affected_rows`.

Answer (score 0):

You must insert space after commas !
Change this line of your code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO record(form_id,form_structure) VALUES('1','value')";
```

with this code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO record (`form_id`, `form_structure`) VALUES ('1', 'value')";
```

Hope it can work
Good luck...